# Strange invalid reads using Valgrind

Tags: c, valgrind

I have a strange case of invalid reads using Valgrind. When I run the sample code from [Tokyo Cabinet](http://fallabs.com/tokyocabinet/spex-en.html#tcbdbapi) in Valgrind `valgrind-3.9.0` using `gcc (Debian 4.7.2-5) 4.7.2` I get the errors below, however, running it on a different physical machine, same tool versions, I don't get any errors. Any idea why?

```
==17440== Invalid read of size 4
==17440==    at 0x4E46360: tcmapputkeep2 (tokyocabinet_all.c:1705)
==17440==    by 0x4E62A8A: tcpathlock (tokyocabinet_all.c:10138)
==17440==    by 0x4E6E7AB: tchdbopen (tokyocabinet_all.c:11779)
==17440==    by 0x4E79BCA: tcbdbopenimpl (tokyocabinet_all.c:19512)
==17440==    by 0x4E7AFED: tcbdbopen (tokyocabinet_all.c:16870)
==17440==    by 0x400CC9: main (in a.out)
==17440==  Address 0x5f1d608 is 24 bytes inside a block of size 26 alloc'd
==17440==    at 0x4C28D84: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:291)
==17440==    by 0x4E5A8A0: tcrealpath (tokyocabinet_all.c:7426)
==17440==    by 0x4E6E797: tchdbopen (tokyocabinet_all.c:11767)
==17440==    by 0x4E79BCA: tcbdbopenimpl (tokyocabinet_all.c:19512)
==17440==    by 0x4E7AFED: tcbdbopen (tokyocabinet_all.c:16870)
==17440==    by 0x400CC9: main (in a.out)
==17440==
hop
bar:step
baz:jump
foo:hop
==17440== Invalid read of size 4
==17440==    at 0x4E46C20: tcmapout2 (tokyocabinet_all.c:1857)
==17440==    by 0x4E62AF3: tcpathunlock (tokyocabinet_all.c:10150)
==17440==    by 0x4E736F5: tchdbclose (tokyocabinet_all.c:11807)
==17440==    by 0x4E7A857: tcbdbcloseimpl (tokyocabinet_all.c:19608)
==17440==    by 0x4E7B0C7: tcbdbclose (tokyocabinet_all.c:16885)
==17440==    by 0x400E9E: main (in a.out)
==17440==  Address 0x5f1d608 is 24 bytes inside a block of size 26 alloc'd
==17440==    at 0x4C28D84: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:291)
==17440==    by 0x4E5A8A0: tcrealpath (tokyocabinet_all.c:7426)
==17440==    by 0x4E6E797: tchdbopen (tokyocabinet_all.c:11767)
==17440==    by 0x4E79BCA: tcbdbopenimpl (tokyocabinet_all.c:19512)
==17440==    by 0x4E7AFED: tcbdbopen (tokyocabinet_all.c:16870)
==17440==    by 0x400CC9: main (in a.out)
```

---

```
#include <tcutil.h>
#include <tcbdb.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
  TCBDB *bdb;
  BDBCUR *cur;
  int ecode;
  char *key, *value;

  /* create the object */
  bdb = tcbdbnew();

  /* open the database */
  if(!tcbdbopen(bdb, "casket.tcb", BDBOWRITER | BDBOCREAT)){
    ecode = tcbdbecode(bdb);
    fprintf(stderr, "open error: %s\n", tcbdberrmsg(ecode));
  }

  /* store records */
  if(!tcbdbput2(bdb, "foo", "hop") ||
     !tcbdbput2(bdb, "bar", "step") ||
     !tcbdbput2(bdb, "baz", "jump")){
    ecode = tcbdbecode(bdb);
    fprintf(stderr, "put error: %s\n", tcbdberrmsg(ecode));
  }

  /* retrieve records */
  value = tcbdbget2(bdb, "foo");
  if(value){
    printf("%s\n", value);
    free(value);
  } else {
    ecode = tcbdbecode(bdb);
    fprintf(stderr, "get error: %s\n", tcbdberrmsg(ecode));
  }

  /* traverse records */
  cur = tcbdbcurnew(bdb);
  tcbdbcurfirst(cur);
  while((key = tcbdbcurkey2(cur)) != NULL){
    value = tcbdbcurval2(cur);
    if(value){
      printf("%s:%s\n", key, value);
      free(value);
    }
    free(key);
    tcbdbcurnext(cur);
  }
  tcbdbcurdel(cur);

  /* close the database */
  if(!tcbdbclose(bdb)){
    ecode = tcbdbecode(bdb);
    fprintf(stderr, "close error: %s\n", tcbdberrmsg(ecode));
  }

  /* delete the object */
  tcbdbdel(bdb);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: For what it's worth, the Tokyo Cabinet website "strongly recommends" using Kyoto Cabinet instead. It's possible that part of the reason for this is bugs in TC that are going unfixed. What version of TC exactly are you using?

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'm using 1.4.48 (latest).

Comment: Just because the author thinks everyone should use Kyoto Cabinet instead of Tokyo Cabinet doesn't prove that Kyoto Cabinet is less buggy. (How many times have the users of an old version of something been burned by the promises of a shiny new version?)

Comment: There is no 1.4.48 in SourceForge. In the Files section we can find only 1.4.32, dated 2009. Also, confusingly, the Tokyo Cabinet Sourceforge page offers a download of something called Tokyo Promenade.  The page you give only has a tarball of 1.4.48; but what happened to 1.4.33 through 1.4.47 Where is the browsable source code repo?

Comment: Oh dear; the `tokyocabinet_all.o` module is made from `cat myconf.c tcutil.c md5.c tchdb.c tcbdb.c tcfdb.c tctdb.c tcadb.c > tokyocabinet_all.c`.

Comment: [1.4.48](http://fallabs.com/tokyocabinet/tokyocabinet-1.4.48.tar.gz)

Answer (score 1):

My gut feeling is that the valgrind error is a false positive.

I suspect it arises out of an optimized `strlen` operation being applied to the 26 byte object, which holds a 25 character string.

In spite of your arguments that the two systems are using an identical compiler, there is probably some difference between the systems in how the `strlen` calls are compiled, or else some other difference, see far below.

On one system, the strlen is being done by doing word-aligned reads of four byte words. The loop fetches some extra bytes beyond the end of the object, which is flagged by Valgrind as an error.

This out of bounds access is harmless, though, because the length operation does not rely on those bytes (it works out the correct string length regardless of what junk may be in those bytes). Also, those out-of-bounds bytes cannot be in an unmapped page if the base address of the word is in a mapped page, because the word is aligned to a multiple of its size, and the base address is in a valid object. (That is, if A is an address divisible by 4, and byte A is inside a valid page, then bytes A + 1 through A + 3 cannot be in an unmapped page: they are in the same page as byte A!)

So, all in all, this Valgrind error probably does not point to any bug in the Tokyo Cabinet.

---

**A possible difference between the two systems is the absolute path to the database.**

Although your `main` program specifies the database as a relative path `"casket.tcb"`, the library converts that to an absolute path using the `realpath` function. The string operations are being done on that path, and the length could be different, unless you have exactly the same directory structure on both systems and are doing these tests in corresponding subdirectories of the different systems.

On one system, the optimized `strlen` could be working with a malloced object that happens to have a size divisible by four, and so the loop optimization doesn't produce an out of bounds access.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I certainly agree with you that it seems to be a false positive from valgrind.

Comment: @PeteDarrow This is almost certainly the correct answer, and should be accepted as such.